# TeXstudio not syncing with external viewer (Evince) on compile

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, viewers, evince

If I highlight a block of text (within the editor) in TeXstudio and click "Build & View", the PDF shown in the internal (windowed) viewer automatically highlights and jumps to the rendered output corresponding to the highlighted editor block:

[image]

If I choose "Build & View" with my external viewer open, however, no such jumping/highlighting happens in the external viewer (though it still occurs normally in the windowed viewer).

So my question: How can I get my external viewer to jump to the spot in my PDF corresponding to text I have highlighted in my editor? I really just want my external editor to mirror exactly what my windowed editor shows when I compile; is this possible?

I'm currently using TeXstudio (2.10.8, Qt Version 5.2.1 on Linux Mint 17.3) with Evince (v 3.10.3) as my external viewer. All of the relevant configuration data is shown here:

[image]

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but none of the suggestions I've read seem to address my particular situation.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is not possible with external viewer.

Comment: @Sigur - Is that answer true for _all_ external viewers? I'm somewhat new to Evince but I seem to remember having a previous configuration in which the external viewer could at least jump to the right _page_.

Comment: I'm not sure but I believe that any independent viewer is able to jump to source code or to go to the scope. They are independent of editors. But let's wait the expert.

Comment: By the way, do you know that you can use the TXS viewer but in separated window?

Comment: @Sigur - I do! And while that solution works fine in principle, I'm pursuing this particular solution as an attempt to "regain" functionality I ('m almost certain I) had before. It's going to be embarrassing if I made the whole external viewer functionality thing up... :/

Comment: this is possible with external viewers using the same SyncTex approach that the internal viewer uses. Whether it's possible with evince and Texstudio, I don't know; I could find details on evince collaborating with gedit and there's many other combinations that are documented on the web. Expect some (or significant) setup time, however. I wouldn't be looking right now if the Texstudio viewer wasn't letting me down (different topic).

Comment: As Matthias has alluded to this is down to the Synctex methodology. It is totally possible with evince and TeXstudio the same as on other platforms Evince and TeXstudio use the DBus to communicate. so either TeXstudio talks to its own viewer or it talks to Evince or you set up a Tee to call both. the easiest solution is to let TeXstudio use Dbus for internal viewer then let internal viewer call a second viewer Atil or Evince via shell commands. A graphic could explain that better but it was rejected as it included a different viewer in that mode. Either viewer can of course reverse call back.